# Java Android SQLite3 not updating the database

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

The database update command is not working for me.  The database keeps the old values after an update command has been issued.

I am using SQLite in an Android Java environment.  I use a helper class called Customer to populate the data items that I am going to update.

```
package com.cis2237.bingp4;

public class Customer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String airline;
    private String status;
    private int miles;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(int id, String name, String airline, String status, int miles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.airline = airline;
        this.status = status;
        this.miles = miles;
    }

    public int getMiles() { return miles; }

    public void setMiles(int miles) { this.miles = miles; }

    public String getStatus() { return status; }

    public void setStatus(String status) { this.status = status; }

    public String getAirline() {
        return airline;
    }

    public void setAirline(String airline) {
        this.airline = airline;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is the update statement in my database helper adapter class.

```
// Columns
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_AIRLINE = "airline";
public static final String COL_STATUS = "status";
public static final String COL_MILES = "miles";

// Column Indexes
public static final int INDEX_ID = 0;
public static final int INDEX_NAME = INDEX_ID + 1;
public static final int INDEX_AIRLINE = INDEX_ID + 2;
public static final int INDEX_STATUS = INDEX_ID + 3;
public static final int INDEX_MILES = INDEX_ID + 4;


//  Edit a customer
public void updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_NAME, customer.getName());
    values.put(COL_AIRLINE, customer.getAirline());
    values.put(COL_STATUS, customer.getStatus());
    values.put(COL_MILES, customer.getMiles());
    mDb.update(TABLE_NAME, values,
            COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(customer.getId())});
}
```

I simply populate the helper class with the columns properly updated using the class setters. I have debugged the database helper adapter class and everything seems to be filled in correctly with the correct updated values just before the code issues the update statement.  I am not receiving any errors.

Comment: Check the return value of update(): `int result = mDb.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(customer.getId())});` If the value is `0` then no row is updated probably because there is no row with the `id` returned by `customer.getId()`

Comment: Yes... result=0

Comment: How could I get the correct ID?  Do I fetch it first with a separate call or can I request it somehow in my update request?

Comment: If you want to use the `update()` method you should first get the id of the row that you want to update and instantiate the `Customer` object with that id and the values of the columns that you want to update. About the *correct id* this is something that you know or can get  its value depending on your requirement.

Comment: I actuall gointo the database through the adb shell.  You are right. It is using the wrong ID.  When I debug the code itis using ID=5445.  The actual ID number on the database is 336.  I don't know where it is getting 5445.  My code says:

Comment: COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(customer.getId())})

Comment: Is there a getCurrentID()?

Comment: There is no current id. But I don't understand your problem. How do you know that a row needs to be updated? What is the condition?